# messages.json missing in Instagram download

Tags: instagram

I want to access the first messages in a certain chat on [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/). Following [this](https://www.guidingtech.com/first-message-instagram-without-scrolling/) post, I downloaded the data from Instagram.
However, I am unable to find the `messages.json` file mentioned in the webpage. Every other website I found also mentions the `messages.json` file. Did a recent update remove the feature of sending this file?

Is there any way I can access my messages?

Answer (score 1):

The previous two answers are FALSE. There is no message folder nor message_1.
Instagram does not download the conversations

Answer (score 0):

The Instagram export format recently changed and there is no longer a messages.json file inside of the downloaded data package. Instead of the single messages.json file with all of the direct message content in it, there is a messages folder that contains subfolders for each direct message conversation on your account, with message_1.json inside (among other files for attachments, or additional json files for long conversations.)

This messages folder export format aligns closely with the Facebook Messenger data that is included in a Facebook data export.

Answer (score 0):

messages.json is message_1.json

Yes, they have made the data export similar to Facebook.
Instead of old messages.json file, you'll see a folder called Messages, which have subfolders inside for individual direct messages. You can see message_1.json file inside these folder, this file have your messages.